# Using multiple sass maps to build a single selector

Tags: css, sass

I'm attempting to create a series of classes that use two sass maps which create the classes and properties.  Here is a simplified version of my maps:

```
$color1:    #aaa;
$color2:    #ccc;
$color3:    #eee;

$colors: ();
$colors: map-merge((
  "color1":    $color1,
  "color2":    $color2,
  "color3":    $color3
), $colors);

$pattern1:    url('pattern1.svg');
$pattern2:    url('pattern2.svg');
$pattern3:    url('pattern3.svg');

$patterns: ();
$patterns: map-merge((
  "pattern1":    $pattern1,
  "pattern2":    $pattern2,
  "pattern3":    $pattern3
), $patterns);
```

Basically what I want to output is a combination of each color and pattern as a class selector (e.g. `.bgp-pattern1-color1`, `.bgp-pattern1-color2`, `.bgp-pattern2-color1`, etc.):

```
.bgp-[pattern]-[color] {
    background: [pattern value] repeat,
                [color value];
}
```

**How do I accomplish this in sass?** I've attempted it with an `@each` function, but cannot get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to accomplish this with combining two `@each` functions:

```
@each $pattern, $patternvalue in $patterns {
  @each $color, $colorvalue in $colors {
    .bgp-#{$pattern}-#{$color} {
      background: $patternvalue repeat,
                  $colorvalue;
    }
  }
}
```

Which outputs:

```
.bgp-pattern1-color1 {background: url("pattern1.svg") repeat, #aaa;}
.bgp-pattern1-color2 {background: url("pattern1.svg") repeat, #ccc;}
.bgp-pattern1-color3 {background: url("pattern1.svg") repeat, #eee;}
.bgp-pattern2-color1 {background: url("pattern2.svg") repeat, #aaa;}
.bgp-pattern2-color2 {background: url("pattern2.svg") repeat, #ccc;}
.bgp-pattern2-color3 {background: url("pattern2.svg") repeat, #eee;}
.bgp-pattern3-color1 {background: url("pattern3.svg") repeat, #aaa;}
.bgp-pattern3-color2 {background: url("pattern3.svg") repeat, #ccc;}
.bgp-pattern3-color3 {background: url("pattern3.svg") repeat, #eee;}
```